# To put/take/place your finger in/into/inside your nose

Tags: word-choice, word-in-context

Which word do you think is appropriate for the following context?
"Jim is very rude. He always puts/takes his finger in/into/inside his nose."
Or, should I say, "He always places his finger inside his nose."?
Edit: I also know the word "nostril". Maybe I should use this word instead of "nose".

Comment: Note that extracting mucus from one's nose is called *nose-picking*. ("He always picks his nose.")

Comment: @userr2684291 Thank you. Can I also say to take out snot from the nose instead of to pick the nose? But I would think it's more impolite.

Comment: You can definitely describe everything in multiple ways, but there's a difference between what you *can* say and what's idiomatic (= natural). *Picking one's nose* is an expression denoting the whole act of a person inserting their finger into the nose and then pulling boogers out of it. *Taking snot out of one's nose* emphasizes the pulling out of boogers. I think a more common verb to use there would be *get* (*get nucus/boogers out of **someone**'s nose*), indicating possible difficulty in doing so. I put *someone* in bold since you don't idiomatically *pick* someone's nose (just your own).

Comment: You're right in saying that *snot* is an impolite way of saying ***nasal** mucus*. (*Booger* just sounds informal, and usually denotes a piece of dried nasal mucus.) I put *nasal* in bold because *mucus* doesn't necessarily mean *nasal mucus*, but it can be clear from the context (*get the mucus out of your nose*) which type you're referring to. Other acceptable, natural ways of saying *getting mucus out of someone's nose* include *getting rid of nasal mucus*, *clearing out mucus in the nose*, *clearing mucus from the nose*, etc.

Comment: Thank you a lot. In addition to getting my answer, I learned some words and phrases like "booger", "clear out mucus in the nose".etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a typical sentence describing this activity:

> He decided he would have to make do with flicking bogeys again, however when he **put** his finger **up** his nose to get some snot his finger got stuck. [The Giant's revenge](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=R_dkAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22finger%20up%20his%20nose%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjno4eylILaAhUBYVAKHQlKDBIQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=%22finger%20up%20his%20nose%22&f=false)

**stick** and **poke** can be used instead of **put**, and **in** can be used instead of **up**, but it is less common. You can also use **have** or **with** if the person spends some time with a finger up his nose.

According to this [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finger%20in%20his%20nose%2Cfinger%20up%20his%20nose%2Cfinger%20into%20his%20nose%2C%20finger%20inside%20his%20nose&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfinger%20in%20his%20nose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinger%20up%20his%20nose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinger%20into%20his%20nose%3B%2Cc0), **into** is rare, and **inside** does not occur at all.

This is not a polite activity, and the words **place** and **nostril** are far too formal.

**take** is the wrong direction: it would be appropriate for removing a finger from a nose, but not for inserting it.